# Indicate if view dissapearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewwillappear

Is it possible to determine if view is dissapearing without additional `BOOL` field and setting it's value to YES/NO in `-viewWillDissapear` `-viewDidDissapear`?

I am trying to determine if view is not dissapearing casued by "back" button (pop to previous controller). Right now I have `isNavigationInProgress` property that do this for me.

Comment: Answer is in your question .. you will catch it when your  `viewWillDissapear`

Comment: What do you mean by " without additional BOOL", can you elaborate it a bit more, it is not clear right now!!!

Comment: the `–viewDidDisappear:` or `–viewWillDisappear:` methods' parameters are for indicating whether the procedure should be animated or not. inside the method you can ignore the parameter but you have to post the received parameter to the `super` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question correctly.

However it looks like you are talking about `isMovingFromParentViewController`, `isMovingToParentViewController`, `isBeingPresented`, `isBeingPresented` and `isBeingDismissed` properties

These properties allows you to get the cause of `-viewWillDissapear` and `-viewDidDissapear` calls.

See more info on Apple site, [UIViewController reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isBeingDismissed)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like you get trough my Enigma question and figure out what I was looking for. The properties you have written was that I was looking for.